# How to update a part of primary key if it is a combination of three columns

Tags: entity-framework, sql-update, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have a table in which I set primary key as combination of three keys like
Statudet_log(ID,STudent_ID,Course_ID,Course_Status)

STudent_ID,Course_ID,Course_Status all made as composite key (primary key)  Now  I want to update course _Status column only using entity framework when I am trying to udpate it  I get this error .

"The property 'Course_Status' is a part of object key information and cannot be modified.I have a condition to make the primary key as unique and with these three columns that is mandatory give solution according to the situation as present I would not like to make ID as primary key and make the rest of the columns as unique.

Comment: Just let ID be the primary key (in terms of relational databases it's the *surrogate key* which is just there for convenience) and make the other three columns unique by an index (i.e. the *natural key*, or *alternate key*). That's all very conventional and I'm curious why you wouldn't want that.

Comment: Gert Arnold thanks for the response. Basically if I made a primary key as a combination of three columns and I would like to update one of them so its not possible to do that ? what if I can update all three columns the one column which I like to update with the new value and the rest of the two columns if i reassign them the same value .

Comment: As you see, EF won't let you.

Comment: Why is Course_Status on this table at all?  Shouldn't it be only on the Course entity?